# Connectedness of subsets

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $(X,d_x)$ be a metric space, and let $A$ be a non connected, non empty, closed subset of $X$.

Can I conclude that $A$ equals to $X$ and $X$ is not connected?

---

It seems that I had wrong understanding towards connectedness, but now I understand it.

And I have a further question: if there is another metric space (Y,dy), can I say that the image of f(A) is a closed subset of Y?

Comment: Surely not. Consider $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric, and $A = \{0, 1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the additional question is *no*. Let $\langle X,d_x\rangle$ be $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric, and let $\langle Y,d_y\rangle$ be $[-1,1]$ with the usual metric. $\Bbb Z$ is a closed subset of $X$ that is not connected. Let

$$f:\Bbb R\to[-1,1]:x\mapsto\frac2\pi\tan^{-1}x\;;$$

$f$ is continuous and maps $\Bbb R$ onto $(-1,1)$. However, $f[\Bbb Z]$ is not closed in $[-1,1]$: both $-1$ and $1$ are limit points of $f[\Bbb Z]$.

For a simpler example, let $X=\Bbb Z^+$ with the usual metric, and let $Y=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ with its usual metric. $X$ is a closed subset of itself that is certainly not connected. The map

$$f:X\to Y:n\mapsto\frac1n$$

is continuous, and $f[X]=\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ is not closed in $Y$, since it has $0$ as a limit point.